Base change using bra-ket notation
If I have two orthonormal bases (of a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$) $A=\{|a_{1}\rangle, |a_{2}\rangle\}$ and $B=\{|b_{1}\rangle, |b_{2}\rangle\}$, the change of base matrix from $A$ to $B$ is given by $U=|b_{1}\rangle\langle a_{1}|+|b_{2}\rangle\langle a_{2}|$. It is clear that $U|a_{1}\rangle=|b_{1}\rangle$.
This would mean that if I have some vector $|\psi\rangle = x_{1}|a_{1}\rangle+x_{2}|a_{2}\rangle$, $U|\psi\rangle=x_{1}|b_{1}\rangle+x_{2}|b_{2}\rangle$. But this new vector is not equal to $|\psi\rangle$ in B.
Now consider this:
$|b_{1}\rangle=|a_{1}\rangle\langle a_{1}|b_{1}\rangle+|a_{2}\rangle\langle a_{2}|b_{1}\rangle \\ |b_{2}\rangle=|a_{1}\rangle\langle a_{1}|b_{2}\rangle+|a_{2}\rangle\langle a_{2}|b_{2}\rangle$
The change of base matrix $U$ is then given by:
$ \begin{pmatrix}
\langle a_{1}|b_{1}\rangle & |a_{1}|b_{2}\rangle\\
\langle a_{2}|b_{1}\rangle & |a_{2}|b_{2}\rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$
Now: $U\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \langle a_{1}|b_{1}\rangle\\ \langle a_{2}|b_{1}\rangle \end{pmatrix}$.
If $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{T}$ represents $|b_{1}\rangle$'s coordinate in $B$, $U\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{T}$ represents $|b_{1}\rangle$'s coordinate in $A$.
So my question is, how does $U|a_{1}\rangle=|b_{1}\rangle$ relate to the coordinate conversion I just showed? Thank you very much!

I would not say your $U=|b_1\rangle\langle a1| + |b_2\rangle\langle a2|$ is a change of basis in the usual sense. You prove it yourself by applying this transformation to $|\psi\rangle=x_1|a_1\rangle+x_2|a_2\rangle$. You would like your transformation to change the coordinates, but your first one actually changes the vectors. It is a linear transformation, just not a basis change. Note that if the basis vectors have different normalizations, $||U|\psi\rangle||$ does not need to coincide with $|||\psi\rangle||$

Thanks for the quick response! I see. If this is not the regular change of basis of a vector space, what is the point of applying such operator ($U$) to a ket $|\psi\rangle$? Am I not just using the coordinates of $|\psi\rangle$ in $A$ but in another basis $B$?

I'm asking this because on my book it says that $U$ represents the base change operator. I just wanted to make sense of the fact that written as an outer product $U$ behaves in a way and written in a matrix in another.

Which book is that? Or what is the precise statement there?

The book is Physical Mathematics by Kevin Cahill, chapter 1, paragraph 12 (Dirac notation). It says: Dirac's outer products show how to change from one basis to another. The sum of outer products $ U = \Sigma_{n=1}^{N} | \alpha_{n}\rangle \langle n| $ maps the ket $| l \rangle $ of the orthonormal basis we started ($ |n \rangle $) into $ | \alpha_{l} \rangle $.

After watching through the youtube lectures by the author of the book mentioned in the comments (link, min. 57), I can post a more thorough reply:
There is, indeed, a relation between $U_1 = \sum_i |b_i\rangle\langle a_i|$ and $U_2 = (\langle a_i|b_j\rangle)_{ij}$. If we express $|b_i\rangle$ in terms of the $A$ basis, then $U_1 = \sum_{ik} \langle a_k|b_i\rangle |a_k\rangle\langle a_i|$, whose matrix elements coincide with $U_2$.
I would still not call it a basis transformation, at least not in the usual sense, because it maps $|a_i\rangle$ onto $|b_i\rangle$, rather than telling you how is $|a_i\rangle$ expressed in terms of $|b_k\rangle$. For example, consider two orthonormal bases $A$ and $B$, related through:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
|b_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|a_1\rangle\ + |a_2\rangle) \\
|b_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-|a_1\rangle\ + |a_2\rangle)
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
|a_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|b_1\rangle\ - |b_2\rangle) \\
|a_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|b_1\rangle\ + |b_2\rangle)
\end{cases} .
\end{equation}
Then, if $U = |b_1\rangle\langle a_1| + |b_2\rangle\langle a_2|$, $U|a_1\rangle = |b_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|a_1\rangle\ + |a_2\rangle)$. Of course, this is no longer the same vector, but notice that it does not even tell you the components of $a_1$ in the $B$ basis. Rather, you can read off the components of $b_1$ in the $A$ basis. This is especially confusing because the notation seems to imply that it gets you from basis $A$ to basis $B$. Rather, the matrix elements of $U = |b_1\rangle\langle a_1| + |b_2\rangle\langle a_2|$ coincide with the transformation that tells you how to express $|b_i\rangle$ in terms of $|a_k\rangle$.
Would I completely reject $U$ as a basis change? Probably not. As we have seen, it is indeed very closely related to what I think many people would consider a "true" basis transformation. However, be careful with how you use it and how you map it to the common notation.
My last comment concerns a more general way of conceiving basis transformations. Consider the resolution of the identity $I=\sum_k|a_k\rangle\langle a_k|$. Then, obviously:
\begin{equation}
|b_i\rangle = I|b_i\rangle = \sum_k\langle a_k|b_i\rangle |a_k\rangle
\end{equation}
which is exactly the basis transformation that expresses $|b_i\rangle$ in the $A$ basis. In this precise sense, a "true" change of basis is nothing but the identity transformation. This makes sense because we don't want whatever we are talking about to change, but only the way we talk about it. This is how I think basis transformations are understood in the most transparent way. On a personal note, I believe that this point of view is not sufficiently emphasized in introductory linear algebra courses, and gets a bit lost in the matrix notation that, in my opinion, hides a lot of the beauty, meaning and simplicity of linear algebra.

About the last part: indeed, $U|b_{1}\rangle = |b_{1}\rangle \langle a_{1} | b_{1} \rangle + | b_{2} \rangle \langle a_{2} | b_{1} \rangle$ is the ket with coefficients in front of the $|b_{i}\rangle$ being the coordinates of $|b_{1} \rangle$ in $A$. If now I apply $U^{*} = \Sigma |a_{i}\rangle \langle b_{i}|$ (the adjoint of $U$, which is a unitary operator) to $U|b_{1}\rangle$ I get $|b_{1}\rangle = |a_{1} \rangle \langle a_{1} | b_{1} \rangle + |a_{2} \rangle \langle a_{2} | b_{1} \rangle $, which, I believe, makes sense.

Well, yes. It makes sense because you are going back to $I|b_1\rangle = |b_1\rangle$. That is perfectly fine, but if you are talking about a coordinate transformation being implemented by $U$ alone, then I'm not so sure that that is straightforward, because again, $U$ changes your vector entirely, not only how you write it (its coordinates).

Yes I was talking about going back going the identity. Thank you!
